# BufferedReader.readLine() hangs when connection forcefully disconnected

Tags: java, android

I am getting data from web service continuously.

```
URLConnection connection;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    try {
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
                "MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int timeoutConnection = Integer.parseInt(preferences.getString(
                "timeout", "60")) * 1000;
        URL urlAddress = new URL(preferences.getString("apiUrl",
                defaultURL));
        connection = urlAddress.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(timeoutConnection);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));
        final String[] inputLine = { null };
        int i=0;
        while (isOnline() && (inputLine[0] = in.readLine()) != null) {   // isOnline checks if connected to internet.
            ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        callback.run(inputLine[0]);
                    }
                });
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ..
        ..
    }
```

This works fine till I am connected to internet. But as soon as I forcefully disconnect, `inputLine[0] = in.readLine()` does not respond. I don't get any exception.

So how may I check if connection is disconnected in between? Using `readLine()` only or something else.  I have seen few solutions which suggest using `BufferedReader.ready()`. I tried that too but it always returns false.

What can I try next?

Comment: You could see what the read timeout is on your `URLConnection`. Perhaps setting a lower value will trigger an earlier exception.

Comment: Although timeout is set to 45 seconds, but I don't get anything even after 45 seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the [read timeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29) on the connection. TCP may take a long time to detect a broken connection if packets are just being dropped.

```
    connection = urlAddress.openConnection();
    connection.setReadTimeout(10000); // 10 seconds
    connection.setConnectTimeout(timeoutConnection);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `.read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)` rather than `.readLine()`, and do your own line processing. Here's the documentation for that `BufferedReader.read` method:

> This method implements the general contract of the corresponding read method of the Reader class. As an additional convenience, it attempts to read as many characters as possible by repeatedly invoking the read method of the underlying stream. This iterated read continues until one of the following conditions becomes true:
>
> - The specified number of characters have been read,
> - The read method of the underlying stream returns -1, indicating end-of-file, or
> - **The ready method of the underlying stream returns false, indicating that further input requests would block.**
>
> If the first read on the underlying stream returns -1 to indicate end-of-file then this method returns -1. Otherwise this method returns the number of characters actually read.

(Emphasis mine.)

It looks as though `read` is guaranteed not to block, because it asks the underlying stream whether it's got anything to offer.

Do remember, though, that it might not return as many characters as you asked for, and it might even return 0.

You still have one problem, though, which is that if it returns 0 then you don't know whether it's because the connection has dropped or just because the web server hasn't produced anything yet.